# Can "echo" stop skipping a line when writing to a file

Tags: linux, bash, file, echo

I'm trying to edit a file with echo command but when I do

```
echo "hello" >> file.txt
```

it is skipping a line. It prints the file like:

```
banana
apple

hello
```

I'm not sure if this is from echo or if the file ends with an "\n" but I would like to write just below the rest of the text:

```
banana
apple
hello
```

EDIT: I see now it is not echo's fault. The file probably ends with a "\n". Is there anyway to bypass this? Can I delete this "\n" or choose in which line I want to write?

Comment: There are a few ways to remove empty lines from a file. I'd suggest looking around this site and unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The file *should* end with a newline. It sounds like it ends with *two* newlines.

Comment: Maybe you should fix whatever created the file in the first place, so it doesn't add a blank line at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another `sed` script which doesn't hard-code any line numbers.

```sh
sed -i '' '${;s/^$/Hello/;t
i\
Hello
}' file.txt
```

Here's a brief breakdown:

- `${` - the actions in braces should only be applied on the last line (address expression `$`)
- `s/^$/Hello/` - if this line is empty, replace it with `Hello`
- `t` - if a substitution took place, we are done (branch to end of script)
- `i\Hello` - insert `Hello` on a new line (that is, if we didn't branch on the previous line)
- `}` - end of braces

This is tested on MacOS; syntax on other Unixes will likely be slightly different. (In particular, on Linux, the `-i` option does not expect or require an argument. Other than that, the script works as such on Debian. Some of the newlines could probably be removed and it would still work, but those are necessary on *BSD `sed`.)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way using the `sed` command altogether with `wc -l file.txt`

The command

`wc -l file.txt`

returns the number of line of file.txt (in my example it would have 2 before echo).
And we can choose which line to write our text with the command:

```
sed -i '2ihello' file.txt
```

it would give us:

```
banana
hello
apple
```

to get what I want can be done like this:

```
echo "aux" >> file.txt

sed -i "3iHello" file.txt
sed '4d' file.txt
```

the last command deletes line 4 the file then becomes:

```
banana
apple
Hello
```